# How to invoke flex binding manually?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I have a code written in flex action script, I am trying to bind a variable to RadioButtonGroup by using selectedValue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"  
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Script>

        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            public static var appObj:String = "first";

            public function setToThird():void {
                appObj = "third";
            }
            public function setToFirst():void {
                appObj = "first";
            }
        ]]>

    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <s:RadioButtonGroup id="travelGroup" selectedValue="{appObj}"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:RadioButton x="167" y="91" label="first" group="{travelGroup}"/>
    <s:RadioButton x="167" y="119" label="second" group="{travelGroup}"/>
    <s:RadioButton x="167" y="151" label="third" group="{travelGroup}"/>
    <s:Label x="195" y="177" text="appObj value is {appObj}" />
    <s:Button x="149" y="277" label="setToThird" click="setToThird()"/>
    <s:Button x="270" y="277" label="setToFirst" click="setToFirst()"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

As I click on `setToThird button` the `appObj value` will be set to string `third` and the selected radio button will be `third`.

Now when I click on the `second` radio button the value of `appObj` is still string `third` and clicking on button `setToThird` will not change to the radio button selection to `third` as the value `appObj` has not changed and the binding (`Bindable`) will not be invoked.

Could anybody please help me on how can I use BindingManager or some other tool to invoke binding manually.

I don't want to implement two way data binding.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and easest way is two-way binding (just add @ symbol before {appObj}). But if you want to avoid this you can take some logic to your side:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:local="*">
<fx:Script>

    <![CDATA[
    [Bindable(event="appObjChanged")]
    public var appObj:String = "first";

    public function setToThird():void {
        appObj = "third";
        dispatchEvent(new Event("appObjChanged"));
    }
    public function setToFirst():void {
        appObj = "first";
        dispatchEvent(new Event("appObjChanged"));
    }
    ]]>

</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    <s:RadioButtonGroup id="travelGroup" selectedValue="{appObj}"/>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:RadioButton x="167" y="91" label="first" group="{travelGroup}"/>
<s:RadioButton x="167" y="119" label="second" group="{travelGroup}"/>
<s:RadioButton x="167" y="151" label="third" group="{travelGroup}"/>
<s:Label x="195" y="177" text="appObj value is {appObj}" />
<s:Button x="149" y="277" label="setToThird" click="setToThird()"/>
<s:Button x="270" y="277" label="setToFirst" click="setToFirst()"/>
</s:Application>
```

P.S. Binding is only dispatching and receiving events and nothing else, so you can customize this easily.